# Why simple_list_item_1 changes its color by itself?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, fragment

I have two simple list views loaded with the `simple_list_view_item_1` on both.

The problem is that in one, the text is black and in the other is light gray.
I thought the style of this list view had default parameters.

The only difference is that the first one is in an activity and the other one is in a fragment. Everything works fine but the color of the text. Why is this happening?

EDIT 1:

Code from the activity:

```
public class Categoria_Divulgacion_Cientifica extends ListActivity {

protected String[] mResumenesDivulgacionCientifica;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categoria__divulgacion_cientifica);

    // Buscar AdView como recurso y cargar una solicitud.
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    Resources resources = getResources();
    mResumenesDivulgacionCientifica = resources.getStringArray(R.array.titulos_divulgacion_cientifica);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mResumenesDivulgacionCientifica);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final String[] links = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.links_divulgacion_cientifica);

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String content = links[position];

            Intent showContent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),lectura_view.class);
            showContent.setData(Uri.parse(content));
            startActivity(showContent);
        }

    });

}
```

Code from the Fragment:

```
ublic class Seccion2 extends ListFragment {

protected String[] mNovedades;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seccion2, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Buscar AdView como recurso y cargar una solicitud.
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    Resources resources = getResources();
    mNovedades = resources.getStringArray(R.array.titulos_novedades);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>       (getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mNovedades);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final String[] links = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.links_novedades);

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String content = links[position];

            Intent showContent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),lectura_view.class);
            showContent.setData(Uri.parse(content));
            startActivity(showContent);
        }

    });

}
```

Activity XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.estudiable.estudiable.Categoria_Emprendimiento"
android:background="@color/blanco">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

    android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/layout_margin_bottom"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom_listview"
    android:clipToPadding="false"

    android:divider="@color/naranja_tigre_2"
    android:dividerHeight="2px"

    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXX"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.estudiable.estudiable.Seccion2"
android:background="@color/blanco">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

    android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/layout_margin_bottom"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom_listview"
    android:clipToPadding="false"

    android:divider="@color/naranja_tigre_2"
    android:dividerHeight="2px"

    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXX"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>enter code here
```

Comment: I don't see anything changing color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` of `Seccion2` class to `getActivity()`.

Do not use **application context** to inflate views, you will get unthemed views.